# Knowing when user has pressed cancel buttons during In-App purchase

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, uialertview

I am writing code for in-app purchases and using a "Processing..." view with an activity indicator to block the "Buy Now" button once a purchase is initiated.  However, how can you tell when the user hits a "Cancel" button since those alert views are coming from the AppStore.app?

Is there a delegate method that gets called when those cancel buttons are pressed?  Or is it a matter of your view becoming `firstResponder` again?  What am I missing here?

If you don't think this is possible, have a look at the "I Am T-Pain" app... they do something very similar and dismiss their view immediately after the cancel button is pressed.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming everything is setup correctly you should have an object implementing *SKPaymentTransactionObserver* which will receive callbacks for transaction success/failure/cancel.

In my example it's the *purchaseManager* object mentioned in this call

```
  [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:purchaseManager];
```

When the user cancels a payment you should receive a callback with a transaction state of cancelled:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {

        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                // THIS IS THE STATE YOU SHOULD SEE
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;

                           ...
}
```

You can use this callback to dismiss your view etc...

Comment: I honestly don't know how I missed that....  I was checking for cancel within a `failedTransaction:` if statement and never realized that it never got into that if statement.  I guess all it takes is another pair of eyes on the situation.  Thanks man!  I really appreciate that

Comment: How does this solve the problem? There is still no distinct "Cancelled" state here so how do we know if the transaction failed or was cancelled before being issued?

Comment: Once you have a failed transaction check if (transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled) . . .

Comment: Unfortunately, when I cancel the error I see in the debugger is error code 2: "Cannot connect to iTunes store".